# Can we update a EKS worker node to reflect a future date?

Tags: amazon-web-services, datetime, kubernetes, containers, amazon-eks

There is a requirement in my project to display the date inside a pod as a future date (for ex: 2028) instead of the current date.

I first tried to add the libfaketime library https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime inside the pod and while that worked as expected, it slowed the application down significantly, and so had to find another workaround, and datefudge did not work for me.

I tried to set the EKS worker node on which my pods were running to a future date, but that just resulted in the worker node becoming "Not Ready" as the kubelet did not work due to the date mismatch on the worker node certificates.
Tried to set the date command while initializing the worker nodes on both managed as well as self managed worker node groups as well, but to no avail.
The default masternode time is only reflected inside the worker.

Is there any other possible way/suggestion for solving this problem ?